# asp.net binding query output into dropdown list in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

this is for ticketing system where the tickets are in different status like 'open, rejected, closed, resolved..'

In asp.net i have a gridview and in the gridview there are textboxes and a dropdownlist.
i can get output from the database and get to populate it in the gridview and also the contents in the dropdown list are also displayed.
how can i get to bind the data of the dropdownlist in the grid to that of the output of the query. if the ticket is closed it should select closed, if the ticket is rejected it should select rejected.

in the onrowCommand, i fetch data from another table and populate into the dropdown list. this is the full list of status like 'oopen, rejected, closed, resolved..'

Comment: Are you getting the status of ticket when you bind the gridview?

Comment: no, am getting the status of that particular ticket, instead all the values in the dropdownlist

Comment: Check out my answer and you need to adapt your code according to that.

Comment: If you do not get status when binding your gridview then you MUST get the row's status in RowDataBound event from database for current. Else you will never to be able to implement your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is missing details like what markup you have used for gridview and also what code you have for RowDataBound event.

So, I have provided a *sample* answer that you can easily adapt to your situation.

I am assuming you have a gridview with an id of `GridView1` that contains the following ItemTemplate ( other columns have been omitted since they are not needed to understand this approach).

You should have a hidden field in the template so you can store the current status of the row; also when you are binding your gridview you should be getting a column called `Status` for the row.

**Sample Markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
              OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound">
<Columns>      
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Status">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfStatus" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Status") %>' />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Then in your RowDataBound event where you are binding the dropdown for the row, you need to get the value of hidden field `hfStatus` and then set the selected item of dropdown using this value.

I have assumed that a method called `GetStatusDropDownListData` is there that gets the data for binding dropdown list.

**Sample RowDataBound event**

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Find the DropDownList in the Row
        DropDownList ddlStatus = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList);
        ddlStatus.DataSource = GetStatusDropDownListData();
        ddlStatus.DataTextField = "Status";
        ddlStatus.DataValueField = "Status";
        ddlStatus.DataBind();


        //Select the Status in DropDownList
        string currentStatus = (e.Row.FindControl("hfStatus") as HiddenField).Value;
        ddlStatus.Items.FindByValue(currentStatus).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this below code of yours made it worked fine
//Select the Status in DropDownList
string currentStatus = (e.Row.FindControl("hfStatus") as HiddenField).Value;
ddlStatus.Items.FindByValue(currentStatus).Selected = true;

Answer (score 0):

i had used this code and its working now:

in asp file:

                            
                                ' Visible = "false" />

in the .cs file
string currentStatus = (e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus") as Label).Text;
ddlStatus.Items.FindByValue(currentStatus).Selected = true;